# Compare result of two table functions using one column from each

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, set-returning-functions

According the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945958/1500111) I have created two functions that use `EXECUTE FORMAT` and return the same table of `(int,smallint)`.

Sample definitions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1(IN _tbl regclass, IN _tbl2 regclass, 
IN field1 integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(id integer, dist smallint)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function2(IN _tbl regclass, IN _tbl2 regclass, 
IN field1 integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(id integer, dist smallint)
```

Both functions return the exact same number of rows. Sample result (**will be always ordered by dist**):

```
(49,0)
(206022,3)
(206041,3)
(92233,4)
```

Is there a way to compare values of the second field between the two functions for the same rows, to ensure that both results are the same:

For example:

```
SELECT
function1('tblp1','tblp2',49),function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49)
```

Returns something like:

```
(49,0)      (49,0)
(206022,3)  (206022,3)
(206041,3)  (206041,3)
(92233,4)   (133,4)
```

Although I am not expecting identical results (each function is a **topK** query and I have ties which are broken arbitrarily / with some optimizations in the second function for faster performance) I can ensure that both functions return correct results, if for each row the second numbers in the results are the same. In the example above, I can ensure I get correct results, because:

```
1st row 0 = 0,
2nd row 3 = 3,
3rd row 3 = 3,
4th row 4 = 4
```

despite the fact that for the 4th row, `92233!=133`

Is there a way to get only the 2nd field of each function result, to batch compare them e.g. with something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(SELECT
function1('tblp1','tblp2',49).field2,
function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49).field2 ) n2
WHERE  function1('tblp1','tblp2',49).field2 != function1('tblp1','tblp2',49).field2;
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: You have to use `select * from function1('tblp1','tblp2',49)` for set returning functions. Do not put them into the select list.

Comment: You added `(will be always ordered by dist)`. Are you sure, this doesn't open possibilities for *false positives*?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It is a topK query (ORDERED BY dist LIMIT k), so results inside the functions are ordered by dist. I want to check in the specific example that  I get one answer with dist =1, two answers with dist =3 and one answer for dist =4 for k=4.  Both functions operate on different tables (the 2nd works on optimized tables) and I want to make sure that both functions return the same dist for all k results. In our case the dist 1 and dist 3 results will be always be the same (there is not a other result with dist=3) but in the case of 4 I might get dist =4 for many results.

Comment: So, rows are returned in *matching* order? The rest is not important for the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That's actually missing the point of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get only the 2nd field of each function result, to batch compare them?

All of the following answers assume that rows are returned in ***matching*** order.

### Postgres 9.3

With the quirky feature of exploding rows from SRF functions returning the *same* number of rows in parallel:

```
SELECT count(*) AS mismatches
FROM  (
   SELECT function1('tblp1','tblp2',49) AS f1
        , function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49) AS f2
   ) sub
WHERE  (f1).dist <> (f2).dist;  -- note the parentheses!
```

The parentheses around the row type are necessary to disambiguate from a possible table reference. [Details in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION)

This defaults to Cartesian product of rows if the number of returned rows is not the same (which would break it completely for you).

### Postgres 9.4

#### `WITH ORDINALITY` to generate row numbers on the fly

You can use `WITH ORDINALITY` to generate a row number o the fly and don't need to depend on pairing the result of SRF functions in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT count(*) AS mismatches
FROM      function1('tblp1','tblp2',49)       WITH ORDINALITY AS f1(id,dist,rn)
FULL JOIN function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49) WITH ORDINALITY AS f2(id,dist,rn) USING (rn)
WHERE  f1.dist IS DISTINCT FROM f2.dist;
```

This works for the same number of rows from each function as well as differing numbers (which would be counted as mismatch).

Related:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### [`ROWS FROM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) to join sets row-by-row

```
SELECT count(*) AS mismatches
FROM   ROWS FROM (function1('tblp1','tblp2',49)
                , function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49)) t(id1, dist1, id2, dist2)
WHERE  t.dist1 IS DISTINCT FROM t.dist2;
```

Related answer:

- [Is it possible to answer queries on a view before fully materializing the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730338/is-it-possible-to-answer-queries-on-a-view-before-fully-materializing-the-view/28731911#28731911)

Aside:
`EXECUTE FORMAT` is not a set plpgsql functionality. `RETURN QUERY` is. [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) is just a convenient function for building a query string, can be used anywhere in SQL or plpgsql.

Comment: Are you sure it works with PostgreSQL 9.3? I get a syntax error and I have seen it only on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-srf.html.

Comment: @Alexandros It is a 9.4+ feature

Comment: @Alexandros As I understand even if it worked in 9.3 it would number a result set possibly not in the same order as inside the function hence the row numbers must be assigned inside the function.

Comment: @Alexandros: Yes, sorry, `WITH ORDINALITY` is for pg 9.4, not 9.3. I added some more.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: `WITH ORDINALITY` number rows just like they are returned from the function. So yes, If the returned order of rows does not match, I see no way to fix this ex post and we would need to add row numbers *inside* each function and return them ...

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the rows are returned from the functions is not guaranteed. If you can return the [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) (`rn` in the below example) from the functions then:

```
select
    count(f1.dist is null or f2.dist is null or null) as diff_count
from
    function1('tblp1','tblp2',49) f1
    inner join
    function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49) f2 using(rn)
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

Checking difference in number of rows:

```
SELECT 
ABS(count(f1a.*)-count(f2a.*))  
FROM
(SELECT f1.dist, row_number()  OVER(ORDER BY f1.dist) rn
FROM
function1('tblp1','tblp2',49) f1)
f1a FULL JOIN 

(SELECT f2.dist, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY f2.dist) rn
FROM
function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49) f2) f2a
USING (rn);
```

Checking difference in dist for same ordered rows:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*)  

FROM

(SELECT f1.dist, row_number()  OVER(ORDER BY f1.dist) rn
FROM
function1('tblp1','tblp2',49) f1)
f1a 
(SELECT f2.dist, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY f2.dist) rn
FROM
function2('tblp1_v2','tblp2_v2',49) f2) f2a
WHERE f1a.rn=f2a.rn
AND f1a.distance <> f2a.distance;
```

A simple OVER() might also work since results of the functions are already ordered but is added for extra check.